# I can't access columns in MS Project VSTO Add-In

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-project

I would like to get and set the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task`
objects displayed in the column `Show on Board` and `Board Status` in a MS Project VSTO Add-In. But it seems that these object members are not accessible programatically. Does anyone have a suggestion how to access these members?

[image: Screenshot of columns in MS Project]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FieldNameToFieldConstant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.fieldnametofieldconstant) to get the field constant for the custom field and then use [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.getfield) to get the *display* value (always a string) of that field. Here is a vba example to get you started; adapt for c# as necessary.

```
Dim fldShowOnBoard As Long
fldShowOnBoard = FieldNameToFieldConstant("Show on Board")

Dim fldStatus
fldStatus = FieldNameToFieldConstant("Board Status")

If ActiveCell.Task.GetField(fldShowOnBoard) = "Yes" Then

    Dim taskStatus As String
    taskStatus = ActiveCell.Task.GetField(fldStatus)
    
    ' do something....
    
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I could not use the FieldNameToField costant due to multilingual issues.
But with your code I got the long representation of the field.
Weirdly those are not stored in the PjField enum.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Rachel Hettinger, I found a solution for my problem.

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task task in Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveProject.Tasks)
{
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.PjField fldShowOnBoard = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.PjField)188745088;
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.PjField fldStatus = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.PjField)188745087;

  string taskShowOnBoard = task.GetField(fldShowOnBoard);
  string taskStatus = task.GetField(fldStatus);

}
```