# MS Project Read Enterprise Custom Fields

Tags: c#, office-interop, ms-project

I need to retrieve values of custom fields assigned to Resource. These custom fields are Enterprise fields - i.e. create in PWA.
In the [Interop.MSProject.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.msproject.resource.enterprisetext1?view=office-project-server#microsoft-office-interop-msproject-resource-enterprisetext1) there are similar in name properties "EnterpriseText1 - 40"
But when I read any of 40 fields all of these are empty.
Configuration of field in test PWA environment looks like this - as example "Cost Type" field with "Text" type[image]

And the assigned value in the mpp file to a Resource (mpp file is connected to PWA to retrive Enterprise Custom fields) like this[image]

Could anybody advice how this enterprise custom field value "CT2" can be retrieved from MPP file with using Interop.MSProject.dll?

Comment: See [I can't access columns in MS Project VSTO Add-In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70570565/i-cant-access-columns-in-ms-project-vsto-add-in/70572466#70572466).

Comment: Rachel, thank you for your reply!